# Is it possible to use USB output and audio port output at the same time?

Tags: audio

I want to use two headphones ***simultaneously***; one USB and another through the audio port listening to the same audio source (i.e iTunes, Spotify, or Netflix) at the same time. Is it possible?

Info about my device,

```
MacBook Pro (Retina, 13-inch, Early 2015)  
2.9 GHz Intel Core i5  
OSX El Capitan 10.11.6
```

Comment: Welcome to Ask Different. It would help us if you provided additional info, such as the types of Apple device your using, OS, etc. Please see [ask] for how to ask good questions that have a better chance at being answered. - From Review -

Comment: @fbara thanks for pointing that out. I have updated the info. :)

Comment: Specifically for headphones, one could use a headphone splitter to turn the single headphone jack into two headphone jacks. Googling for "headphone splitter" turns up many options - I have seen them for under $5.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The short answer is ***YES***.

What you are asking is called "aggregating your device."  This is done through *MIDI Audio Setup* found in Applications -> Utilities

In the image below, MIDI Audio Devices is opened up.  I have highlighed the two *output* audio devices I want to aggregate; notice both of them are outputs (0 in/ 2 out).

[image]

When you click the "+", select "Create Aggregate Device"

[image]

When you create your device, just select the devices from the right you want to aggregate into one.  In my example, I have selected the Built in Audio and my USB Codec from the previous example.

[image]

Close MIDI Audio Setup.  When you open Sound Preferences, you will see the new output device.  Select your new aggregated device to have sound output on all devices.

[image]

Comment: I think that may be the opposite of what the OP wanted [though I'm guessing]. That's for defining 'separate output per source' in effect, rather than 'multiple outputs for a given source'. I'd be tempted to just tweak this up to cover both bases, add a paragraph on Audio Midi Setup with Multi-Output &/or Aggregate devices.

Comment: @Tetsujin yes, I meant more like watching a movie through two headphones and not exactly what Allan described.

Comment: @Allan is it possible to make all sound output through different devices instead of just changing output for system and media sound?

Comment: @Tetsujin...I modified the question so it was clearer and rewrote my answer accordingly.  Hope it helps.