# How could I multicast audio on MacOSX

Tags: audio, macos

How could I multicast audio on MacOSX? Suppose I have headphone jack on mbp and a usb hub and an external soundcard and god knows what else and I don't have a headphone preamp: could I send audio to multiple outputs (2 sets of headphones) somehow? In Settings GUI apple allows to select single output only.

Comment: Something like Aggregate Device? https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT202000

Comment: Assuming they are wired as Bluetooth isn’t going to work, look at this solution: https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/251360/119271

Comment: Yes Mateusz, Aggregate Device is what I was looking for. Feel free to farm this out as an answer.